# How to bypass loading the value of the variable if it does not exist

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have code:

```
firstOpCardID = usCardOponent.get(1).getId() + "";
secondOpCardID = usCardOponent.get(2).getId() + "";
thirdOpCardID = usCardOponent.get(3).getId() + "";
```

usCardOponent is a LinkedHashMap which not every time has all three elements.
For example: 
In game are two cards (from max 3 )- First and Third or Second and Third etc. How I can read card id belonging only to this two cards.

Below I present method:

```
public void saveInfoToXML(){

        String playerNick =  userLbl.getText();
        String playerHP = plyHP.getText();
        String firstPlyCardID = null;
        String secondPlyCardID = null;
        String thirdPlyCardID = null;
        String firstOpCardID = null;
        String secondOpCardID = null;
        String thirdOpCardID = null;


        String opponentNick =  opNick.getText();
        String opponentHP = opHP.getText();
         firstOpCardID = usCardOponent.get(1).getId() + "";
         secondOpCardID = usCardOponent.get(2).getId() + "";
         thirdOpCardID = usCardOponent.get(3).getId() + "";



                    //if(usCardPlayer.size() == 3){
                         firstPlyCardID = usCardPlayer.get(1).getId() + "";
                         secondPlyCardID = usCardPlayer.get(2).getId() + "";
                         thirdPlyCardID = usCardPlayer.get(3).getId() + "";

                         try {
                                savePoint.SaveStatus(playerNick, playerHP, firstPlyCardID, secondPlyCardID, thirdPlyCardID, opponentNick, opponentHP, firstOpCardID, secondOpCardID, thirdOpCardID);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    //} 



    }
```

In case where any of idcard doesn't exists, console shows errors.
If someone has some idea how to fix this problem I would be very gratefull

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: You can just check the size using `usCardOponent.size()` and then decide the outcome based on the number of values it has.

Comment: Why use any variables at all? Why not an array? Or a list? Or leave the values where they are?

Comment: Think about why the element at that index is not available and either ensure that it is or implement appropriate case handling.

Comment: Index should begin at 0, you should use an Arraylist to access it by index. Beside of this code style comments : What is the difficutly you meet, what have you tried?,

Comment: I try to create condition where I check is this Map element exist or not